# Правильная конструкция предложения

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, редактура, корректура

*Как же прекрасен этот туман, растворяющийся в серебристом свете Луны и обвивающий своими влажными щупальцами деревья от корней до самых высоких крон, чьи потемневшие стволы застыли в темноте плотной стеной огибающей полным кругом всё озеро!*

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно сконструировать предложение. Правильно ли оно по смыслу и пунктуации?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Исправил вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То, что вы описываете, и вправду красиво. Но, думаю, есть несколько неточностей.

*Потемневшие стволы застыли в темноте* — если это такой специальный повтор однокоренных слов, то мне кажется, что он контекстом никак не оправдан (ведь в описании присутствует серебристый свет луны — значит, уже не темнота).

Слово "луна" я бы написала со строчной буквы.
После "стеной" необходима запятая (далее идет причастный оборот).

Туман на озерах появляется на поверхности — иногда он просто стелется крупными обрывками, иногда обволакивает, заполняет все вокруг, иногда затейливо клубится.
*Растворяющийся* же туман более похож на облачка или хлопья. Они именно растворяются в воздухе: тают и исчезают, но никоим образом не превращаются в щупальца, способные обвить деревья сверху донизу.
Нужен, считаю, другой глагол или причастие.

[Огибать](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/201443/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) — располагаясь вокруг чего-либо, окружать собой, опоясывать.
Сочетание *полным кругом* оригинальное, встречается нечасто. Я бы его обязательно использовала, только с иным глаголом.

"Действующих лиц" в предложении много, и в самом конце уже не совсем понятно, к чему именно относится восклицательный знак и что же так прекрасно (туман, деревья, озеро?).

В качестве варианта:
*Зарождающийся в серебристом свете луны и обвивающий своими влажными щупальцами деревья, от корней до самых высоких крон, — потемневшие стволы застыли плотной стеной, ограждающей полным кругом всё озеро, — как же прекрасен этот туман!*

P. S. Спасибо за вопрос.
И просто для хорошего настроения: [озеро Парика](https://www.visitestonia.com/ru/%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) в форме сердца (Эстония).

Comment: Спасибо большое! Многое подчерпнул из вашего ответа. Спасибо!

Comment: Возможно,  замечания по лексике и описанию явления действительно корректны (я в своем ответе этого не касалось), но предлагаемая грамматика не выдерживает никакой критики. О подробностях говорить не буду.